# Is it OK for a TL431 to be power cycled at high frequency?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, switching-regulator, tl431

For a project I have a switched capacitor supply that creates a +15V/-15V output from a single positive input. I also need a small (+-20mA) 5V supply (crude regulation is OK). So I thought I could piggyback on the switching that is already occuring and came up with this:

[image]

`SW` is the "virtual" ground from the switching supply that is constantly switching between `+15V` and `GND` at 25 kHz. The 5V output should be referenced to this. `C1` allows only small pulses to pass trough `Q1` each cycle. `R3` provides a discharge path for `C1` every cycle. When the output reaches 5V the TL431 will start stealing base current from `Q1`, charging `C1` and thus turning `Q1` off until at least the next cycle (pulse skipping). Seems to work  well in simulation:

[image]

But the TL431 is effectively completely power cycled at 25 kHz. Being a "complex" chip rather then a simple passive component I was wondering if this OK or is it something that's being frowned upon and has possible caveats long term?

Comment: How does Q1 get biased?

Comment: @Andyaka What do you mean? It's just a emitter follower. When the `SW` node is at `+15V` `C1` gets discharged trough `R3`. When `SW` goes to `GND` `C1` charges trough `Q1`'s BE junction and thus allows a short pulse to pass trough `Q1` every cycle.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Being a "complex" chip rather then a simple passive component I was wondering if this OK or is it something that's being frowned upon and has possible caveats long term?

The TL431 [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tl431.pdf) contains a graph for the *Pulse Response*:

[image]

Given the datasheet documents the characterised pulse response for a 100 kHz frequency, assume should be OK for long term use at 25 kHz.

Comment: Good answer, upvoted.